# Diagonalizable vector-space-endomorphisms.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, linear-transformations, diagonalization

I'm new here and need help with a problem:

Let $A$ be in $Mat(n,K)$ and $f_A:K^n \rightarrow K^n, f_A(x)=Ax.$

I have to show, that $A$ is similar to a diagonal Matrix $D$ $\iff$ $f_A$ is diagonalisable.

Thanks.
[feelsbadman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kyo02.png)

Comment: If A is similar to a diagonal matrix D than by definition A is diagonalisable.

Comment: If A is diagonalisable than also by definition its similar to a some diagonal matrix.